# No bean found of type interface reactivefeign.ReactiveFeignBuilder for "service"

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-feign, spring-webclient, reactive-feign-client

I have created a simple Reacting Feign Client

```
@ReactiveFeignClient(name = "mechanic-service", path = "${mechanic.service.url}")
public interface MechanicClient {
    @GetMapping("/mechanic-api/hello")
    Mono<HelloWorldDetails> hi();
}
```

Now when I @Autowire it in my service class, IntelliJ gives an error:

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'MechanicClient' type found.

This is my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableReactiveFeignClients
public class CustomerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CustomerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <feign-reactor.version>3.1.1</feign-reactor.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.playtika.reactivefeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-reactor-spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${feign-reactor.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and when I start the server I get the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'helloWorldController': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'mechClient'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name
> 'com.emech.customer.config.feign.MechanicClient': FactoryBean threw
> exception on object creation; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean found of type interface
> reactivefeign.ReactiveFeignBuilder for mechanic-service   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]

Can anyone guide me, what I'm missing, I'm new to Reactive Feign Client.
Thanks

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: no, I wasn't able to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You should specify client in `@EnableReactiveFeignClients` annotation

```
@EnableReactiveFeignClients(clients = {MechanicClient.class})
```